# QGIS3.12 vector drop-down menu does not have openstreetmap as an option

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

QGIS3.12 vector drop-down menu does not have OpenStreetMap as an option. Processing is enabled, but still nothing... I'm new to this platform and have no idea what I should do to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [QuickOSM](https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM) plugin instead. You can install it using "Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins..." menu.

Some tutorial on how to use QuickOSM:

- [Searching and Downloading OpenStreetMap Data (QGIS3)](http://www.qgistutorials.com/it/docs/3/downloading_osm_data.html)
- Video Tutorials:

  - [QuickOSM](https://vimeo.com/108737868)
  - [How to smart download OpenStreetMap spatial data with QGIS3 and QuickOSM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHEO9mljbqo)
  - [Quick OSM ( download data from Open Street Map by query)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Vj00dgdDzo)

OR

There is another plugin, [OSM Downloader](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMDownloader/). But QuickOSM has a lot of options.